# 'create table' event ... with Apache Cassandra

Tags: create-table, cqlsh, cassandra-2.1

I am trying to run a Cassandra server. For that i just followed the tutorial on that page (http://www.opencredo.com/2014/10/23/spring-data-cassandra-overview/).

I am stuck on the step: Setting up Cassandra

When i try to create a table as described in tutorial i got an ErrorMessage code=2000.

```
cqlsh:events> CREATE TABLE event ( 
  type text, bucket text, id timeuuid, tags set, 
  PRIMARY KEY (( type, bucket), id)) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (id DESC);

ErrorMessage code=2000 [Syntax error in CQL query] message="line 1:66
mismatched input ',' expecting '<' (..., id timeuuid, tags set[,] PRIMARY...)"
```

After intensive research I still don't know what the problem here is, does anyone have a clue what a problem could be here?

My version is:

```
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 2.1.2 | CQL spec 3.2.0 | Native protocol v3]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the type of the set like :

```
CREATE TABLE event (
  type text,
  bucket text,
  id timeuuid,
  tags set<text>,
  PRIMARY KEY ((type, bucket), id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (id DESC);
```

For more information see [this link](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/cql/cql_using/use_set_t.html)